# passing DF to utility as parameter and trying to access the DF in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have created a data frame in test.py and called a utility test1.py and passed the dataframe as a parameter to that utility. when I try to use `df.rdd.collect()` inside utility, then it's not working. getting error like variable doesn't have any parameter like `rdd`. can you help me with how to read data frame inside utility?

for example:

#test.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from test1 import samplefunction


spark = SparkSession.builder.app("examples").getOrCreate
dat = [(1234, "2021-12-13","2021-12-13T17:55:26+0000",10),(1234, "2021-12-12","2021-12-12T17:55:26+0000",1),(1234, "2021-12-11","2021-12-11T17:55:26+0000",621))]
col = [transid,create_dt,create_ts,purge]

df = spark.CreateDateframe(data = dat, schema = col)

result = samplefunction(df)
print(result)
```

#test1.py

```
def samplefunction(df):
 total = 0
 msg = ""
  for row in df.rdd.collect():
    value1 = f'Transaction ID : {int(row.col1 value)}\n'
    value2 = f'Created Date : {str(row.col2 value)}\n'
    value3 = f'Created Time : {str(row.col3 value)}\n'
    value4 = f'Purged : {int(row.col4 value)}\n'

    total = total + row.col4 value
    msg = msg + value1 + value2 + value3 + value4
  return msg
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I have created data frame and created generic utility(test1.py) to print the data in some specific format. When I passed the data frame to that utility, utility didn't consider that as data frame instead it picked as parameter. So not able to perform rdd.collect() operation. i have updated my code with more details.

Comment: It is important to send an rdd df, could you please check my update?

Comment: Thanks, I have checked and trying out now, seems we can't pass a data frame as parameter to another function in another module. I'm trying to use list of list, let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are essential errors in your code. But you can use the following code I think you are describing;

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def samplefunction(df):
    total = 0
    msg = ""
    for row in df.rdd.collect():
        value1 = f'Transaction ID : {int(row["transid"])}\n'
        value2 = f'Created Date : {str(row["create_dt"])}\n'
        value3 = f'Created Time : {str(row["create_ts"])}\n'
        value4 = f'Purged : {int(row["purge"])}\n'

        total += int(row["purge"])
        msg = msg + value1 + value2 + value3 + value4


    return total

if __name__ == '__main__':

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    dat = [(1234, "2021-12-13", "2021-12-13T17:55:26+0000", 10), (1234, "2021-12-12", "2021-12-12T17:55:26+0000", 1), (1234, "2021-12-11", "2021-12-11T17:55:26+0000", 621)]
    col = ['transid', 'create_dt', 'create_ts', 'purge']

    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dat)
    dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF(col)

    result = samplefunction(dfFromRDD1)
    print(result)


>>> 632
```

1. You can not add integers and strings as you have described in your `samplefunction` function
2. Once you have turned your df from rdd to Df, you can use `.collect()` for iteration.
   Ps: please specify if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, My requirement is different and  I have updated the request with more details.